# Decoding ReadableByteStreams

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
var url = 'http://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=foo&searchType=image';

window.fetch(url)
  .then(decode)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

function decode(r) {
  // r.body is a ReadableByteStream - how do I decode it to a string?
}
```

`r.body` is a `ReadableByteStream` - how do I decode it to a string?

Is `decode` the correct term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built in decoder for this purpose:

```
window.fetch(url)
  .then(r => r.text())
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: OK, thanks I didn't know that. And if I wanted to do it "manually"?

Comment: You can use `r.body.getReader()` and read chunks of data from it using `read()` method, or you can create new stream from it using pipeThought method. For more info see examples here: https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#rs-get-reader

Comment: Also to decode UIntArray chunks, which you will get from `read()`, as a utf-8 string -  you can use `TextDecoder`, something like: `new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(data);`